# How to revise the use of "and" in this kind of sentence?

Tags: grammar

When writing sentences, I often want to use "and" after "and" between different objects.

See the examples:

> 1. When writing stories, I often use a descriptive metaphor and simple and fresh plot to…
> 2. Last night, I saw a truck with its logo and black and yellow company name.

So my point is:

First sentence: `metaphor and plot`, the `and` in `simple and fresh` adjective made the first less structure.

Second sentence: logo, `and` black `and` yellow company name.

I know they are probably both grammatical. But I am wondering if there are any ways to improve the sentence so that it flows better. Maybe one "and"? Many thanks. Any thoughts will be grateful.

Update: Sorry for being so confusing. In the second sentence, the logo and sign are two objects. I've revised it to company name. Thanks for the advise so far.

Comment: It might be better to try to find a good way to rephrase your ambiguous sentences. However, in the case like this, and perhaps we couldn't come up with a good alternative, we could try this trick: *I often use a descriptive metaphor and simple-and-fresh plot to ...*, or *I saw a truck with its logo and black-and-yellow company name.*

Answer (score 2):

In the first sentence there are a number of connectors that can be used:

1. as well as
2. in conjunction with

Additionally, you could keep "and" and just use a comma between the two adjectives: "metaphor and simple, fresh plot to..."

In the second sentence the repeated "and" is almost unavoidable. You could break it up in writing by inserting a comma to clearly separate the constituents: "logo, and black and yellow sign..."

Answer (score 0):

To improve those 2 specific examples:

1. When writing stories, I often use a descriptive metaphor with a simple and fresh plot to... OR
   1.a When writing stories I often use a descriptive metaphor; a simple and fresh plot to...
2. Last night, I saw a truck with its black and yellow logo.  OR
   2a. Last night, I saw a truck with its logo; a black and yellow sign.

The semi colon prevents a comma splice, because the 1st "and" doesn't fit there.

edit: I'm assuming for the 2nd sentence that the black and yellow sign are descriptors of the logo.

Comment: Adding a semicolon splits the sentence into two discrete but related ideas, which changes the meaning. Using *with* subordinates *plot* to *metaphor*, also changing the meaning. It appears you've missed the question's edit as well (changing *sign* to *company name* to clarify that there are two distinct items on the truck).